# Hide/Remove We can't find products matching the selection. message

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

How can I hide or remove this message
We can't find products matching the selection
It's appear on all pages

Magento version 2.3.3

[image: the message]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW `inventory_stock_1` AS select
 distinct `legacy_stock_status`.`product_id` AS `product_id`,
 `legacy_stock_status`.`website_id` AS `website_id`,
 `legacy_stock_status`.`stock_id` AS `stock_id`,
 `legacy_stock_status`.`qty` AS `quantity`,
 `legacy_stock_status`.`stock_status` AS `is_salable`,
 `product`.`sku` AS `sku` from
 ( `cataloginventory_stock_status` `legacy_stock_status` join `catalog_product_entity` `product` on
     (( `legacy_stock_status`.`product_id` = `product`.`entity_id` )));
```

and then

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Might solve your problem
Happy coding